# Android drawer navigation click events

Tags: java, android, onclick, onclicklistener, navigation-drawer

I made a drawer navigation based on a tutorial on the internet and I followed everything but when I open my app everything is working correctly except my onclick event. I'm pretty new to android (2 weeks) and tried to figure it out by myself but it didn't work out. I tries onclicklistener but that one didn't give any possitive feedback for me.

How do I make a click event that will take me to another activity?

my code:

```
public class LayoutOneActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    String[] menu;
    DrawerLayout dLayout;
    ListView dList;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_one);        

        Resources res = getResources();
        String [] menu_items = res.getStringArray(R.array.menu_items); // String array where the menu items will be stored        

            menu = menu_items; // Variable for the menu items
            dLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout); // Looking for the id "drawer_layout" and apply as layout
            dList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer); // Looking for the listview where the items will be stored
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,menu);// Making a new adapter
            dList.setAdapter(adapter);// Give the list-layout the variable "adapter" which is an adapter (obviously)            
            dList.setSelector(R.drawable.back);// Sets the colour of the list-layout

            dList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
            {   
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id) 
                {

                  dLayout.closeDrawers();// The layout will be clossed when clicked outside the layout
                  Bundle args = new Bundle();// New bundle which will parse the data between various activities
                  args.putString("Menu", menu[position]);
                  Fragment detail = new DetailFragment();
                  detail.setArguments(args);
                  FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                  fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, detail).commit();
            }
         });
      }
```

layout_one

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">
     <FrameLayout
         android:id="@+id/content_frame"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">
          <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:background="@drawable/bg">

     <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"        
         android:orientation="vertical">

         <LinearLayout
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="90dp"
             android:orientation="horizontal">

             <Button
                 android:layout_width="80dp"
                 android:layout_height="85dp"
                 android:background="@drawable/button"
                 android:onClick="openNewActivity1"
                 android:text="@string/clickActivity1" />

             <Button
                 android:layout_width="80dp"
                 android:layout_height="85dp"
                 android:background="@drawable/button"
                 android:onClick="openNewActivity2"
                 android:text="@string/clickActivity2" />

             <Button
                 android:layout_width="80dp"
                 android:layout_height="85dp"
                 android:background="@drawable/button"
                 android:onClick="openNewActivity3"
                 android:text="@string/clickActivity3" />
         </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="90dp"
             android:orientation="horizontal">

             <Button
                 android:layout_width="80dp"
                 android:layout_height="85dp"
                 android:background="@drawable/button"
                 android:onClick="openNewActivity4"
                 android:text="@string/clickActivity4"/>

             <Button
                 android:layout_width="80dp"
                 android:layout_height="85dp"
                 android:background="@drawable/button"
                 android:onClick="openNewActivity5"
                 android:text="@string/clickActivity5"/>

             <Button
android:layout_width="80dp"
               android:layout_height="85dp"
                 android:background="@drawable/button"
                 android:onClick="openNewActivity6"
                 android:text="@string/clickActivity6"/>
         </LinearLayout>

     </LinearLayout>

 </RelativeLayout> </FrameLayout>

         <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
         android:layout_width="240dp"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_gravity="start"
         android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
         android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
         android:dividerHeight="0dp"
         android:background="#fff"/> </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

menu_detail_fragment

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <LinearLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:background="#5ba4e5"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">
         <TextView
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:textSize="40px"
             android:textColor="#ffffff"
             android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/detail"/> </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please describe what doesn't work and how.

Comment: I updated with information you asked

Answer (score 1):

To set a navigation menu onClickListener you have to implement the NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener interface on the Activity.

On the onCreate method you have to define the navigation onClickListener to the context Activity like this:

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Then you have to Override the method

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item)
```

I write an example of how to implement the method below:

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        EventFragment eventFragment = new EventFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("selectedEvent", "Urban");
        eventFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mainFrame,eventFragment).commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        EventFragment eventFragment = new EventFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("selectedEvent", "Cosmos");
        eventFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mainFrame,eventFragment).commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        EventFragment eventFragment = new EventFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("selectedEvent", "Sink");
        eventFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mainFrame,eventFragment).commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {
        ShopListFragment intent = new ShopListFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mainFrame, intent).commit();

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(START);
    return true;
}
```